# Saying the Ribono Shel Olom after counting the Omer

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer

If one is no longer counting the Omer with a Brocho can one still recite the Ribono Shel Olom prayer?

Comment: Why might you think one can or cannot do so or that they are related at all? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score -2):

I assume that you are referring to the paragraph that appears in most siddurim following the actual counting. This is an additional / optional paragraph that is not part of the essential mitzvah of counting.

Additionally, part of the paragraph references one of the Kabbalistic "sefirah" terms related to that day. The point is, that each day, there is a mitzvah to count, with or without a bracha. If you count without a bracha, you still fulfilled the mitzvah of counting that day. The saying of the vracha is contingent on the concept of having "temimot" meaning "full", "Complete" or "unblemished", and since you missed a day, you've lost the completeness, and cannot say the bracha. But, obviously, you still can and MUST count, daily.

For either of these two reasons, you can recite the Ribbono shel Olam following the counting.

Comment: Isn't the bracha not said because there is a doubt if one is obligated or not?

Comment: @DoubleAA Sorry, I don't understand. "Obligated or not .. " for what? To say the bracha if you forgot, to say bracha at all (even if you never forgot) or to continue counting if you forgot a day?

Comment: The latter. [15]

Comment: @DoubleAA - Hmmm. I have to look this up. That factor would change my answer.

Answer (score -2):

The Chok Yakov ( O. Ch.489) writes not to say  the kabalistic tefilos  after counting the Omer.

Comment: He says that in general, unrelated to whether or not you are counting with a Bracha, so this doesn't really address the question.